# State and prove a characterization of those graph $G$ with $/gamma(G)=1$

Tags: graph-theory

I know $\gamma (K_{1,n})=1$ and  $\gamma (c_3)=1$ and  $\gamma (p_3)=1$ but I cant not prove , and Are there other $G$ that $\gamma(G)=1$

Answer (score 1):

Given a graph $G$ consider the graph $G'$ obtained by appending a vertex $v$ and joining it to every vertex of $G$, this gives you a vast family of graphs with $\gamma(G)=1$. (In fact it gives you all of them, as having $\gamma(G)=1$ is the same as having a vertex connected to everything else).